# I'm using com_jalang in my site and languages are not auto loading

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, extensions

I am making a multi-language joomla 3.x site and I'm using com_jalang to help me achieve my goal. I've installed language packs in the backend, but i can not see them when my site loads. I should see them in the language switcher select box. Can someone help me please???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Extensions > Language Manager`. Click on `Content` in sidebar. Add your installed languages there too. Installing language dosen't create content language automatically.

You also should have "Default page" for every language. Otherwise it wont show up in language switcher.

To get it right, follow [this tutorial](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-configuration-multilanguage-site.html).